# PHP: New variable from string concatenated with variable (variable-variables)

Tags: php, variable-variables

I am having a basic php problem that I haven't been able to resolve and I would also like to understand WHY!

```
 $upperValueCB = 10;
 $passNodeMatrixSource = 'CB';

 $topValue= '$upperValue'.$passNodeMatrixSource;

 echo $topValue;
```

OUTPUT 
$upperValueCB

but I want OUTPUT as the variable's value 10.

How can I make PHP read the $dollar-phrase as a variable and not a string?

Comment: `$topValue = $upperValueCB . $passNodeMatrixSource;`? Why the quotes?

Comment: $upperValue isn-t a variable it's a string

Comment: Ok... I guess I don't quite understand the problem then...

Comment: show the exact output you want to get

Comment: @yefrem, I said I wanted the variable-s value 10

Comment: What you're asking for is variable variables appearantly. But what you actually want is to learn about arrays.

Comment: @Mario Yeah I've learnt a new thing today, variable variables, but why are you concerned about my arrays?

Comment: It's a useful feature, but rightly hard to google. Point being, newcomers often use it feather-headed as substitute for arrays/dictionaries.

Comment: @mario, oh ok thanks! also...ADDED variable variables as a tag to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$varName = 'upperValue' . $passNodeMatrixSource;
$topValue = $$varName;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Chosen for the link! Can you put it in the answer too!!

Answer (score 4):

This little example might illustrate what you are about to do:

```
<?php

$a = 'b';
$b = 10;

echo ${$a}; // will output 10
```

So you will have to change your example to:

```
$upperValueCB = 10;
$passNodeMatrixSource = 'CB';

$topValue= 'upperValue'.$passNodeMatrixSource;

echo ${$topValue}; // will output 10
```

Comment: I don't think so. Have you tested it? it outputs 10 because the variable names `$b` or `$upperValueCB` will being generated dynamically

Comment: Hehe.. No problem.. Note that the syntax of @AlucardTheRipper is also correct

Comment: Cheers again, gave three plus ones but gave the correct to @alucardtheripper for the php manual link and because he only HAD 1 point AND was first correct too I think!

Comment: No problem. Also note that the syntax of his answer is shorter than my. Programmers are lazy. isn't it ? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way :

```
$upperValueCB = 10;
$passNodeMatrixSource = 'CB';

$topValue= ${'upperValue'.$passNodeMatrixSource};

echo $topValue;
```

Because `upperValueCB` is the var name, if you want PHP to understand which var to use, you have to give the var name.
For that, you can use static way like `$upperValueCB`
or using a string like this : `${'upperValueCB'}`
or using a third var containing the var name `$var = 'upperValueCB'; $$var;`

Comment: Thanks +1, thought the problem was parsing '' not variable naming

Comment: Thank's for that, but I think the problem was well in the method used to call the var correctly. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $upperValueCB = 10;
 $passNodeMatrixSource = 'CB';

 $topValue= 'upperValue'.$passNodeMatrixSource;

 echo ${$topValue};
```

Comment: This will print "10CB" instead of "10"